# Adding data to custom dataLayer variable in GTM

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

Update note: I believe this is different from the linked "duplicate" answer because I'm not asking how to use a variable name as the "name" (since I've shown I know how to do that), but rather, how to achieve the intended result below.

I currently have the custom data layer variable as an array that is populated in the following notation:

```
myArray.push({"name":"value"});
```

That said, the expected output should be like so:

```
[{"name1":"value1", "name2":"value2", "name3":"value3"}]
```

Now my current dilemma is that I need to add another item in the array, however, my "name" is stored in a variable.

Using the variable name leads to the variable name being used as the "name", so that won't work.

```
myArray.push({varName:"value"});
```

Results in:

```
[{"varName":"value"}]
```

I've also tried creating a new object, and inserting that in, but that just adds the object into the array without the correct "name".

```
var myObject = {};
myObject[varName] = "value";

myArray.push(myObject);
```

Results in:

```
[{"Message": {"varName":"value"}}]
```

Now, I'm out of ideas on how to go about with this, so any help is much appreciated!

TIA

Comment: The bracket notation is the way to go... I am not sure why that is not working for you. Please show your actual code so we can help you find the real issue.

Comment: Perhaps the value of `varName` isn't what you think it is?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/mixiva/1/edit?js,console — cannot reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use ECMAScript 2015 you can do with [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```
myArray.push({[varName]:"value"});
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand your question if you wanted to delete the variable "name" inside myArray or update it?

For adding new variables inside myArray just do another .push for name

```
myArray.push = [{
'name': 'value',
'name1': 'value',
'name2': 'value',
'name3': 'value',
}];
```

For removing the variable name this code would do it for more information about flushing variable read this Simo Ahava's blog http://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/remember-to-flush-unused-data-layer-variables/

```
myArray.push = [{

'name': undefined,
'name1': 'value',
'name2': 'value',
'name3': 'value',

}];
```